# Using Jquery, what is the best way to read the 3rd column in a row from a html table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have this code that read the first value in a html table

```
var firstNameinFirstCol = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:first').text();
```

this work great but now I need something that reads the 3rd column in that same row.  Something like this

```
var lastNameinThirdCol = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:third').text();
```

does Jquery support something similar to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) (instead of `parents`) and [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)?

```
var lastNameinThirdCol = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
```